# What about? vs. How about?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

As far as I know that we can use "What about ...?" to indicate that we're asking the same question as before.

Example:

Gerry: Do you like bananas?

Kathy: Yes.

Gerry: What about apples?

Kathy: Yes.

Gerry: What about oranges?

Kathy: Yes.

Gerry: What about watermelons?

Kathy: No.

Can we use "How about ...?" to serve the same purposes?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in saying ***how about*** instead of ***what about*** in this specific context. The two expressions are very close in meaning and many times can be used pretty much interchangeably, but, I guess, there are circumstances when one is more preferable over the other.

Example:

> — Hey, do you like apples?
>   — Yes.
>   — **How about pineapples?** Do you like them too?

Comment: Why is it preferable in this context?  In another word, under what circumstances one is preferable over the other? Thanks!

Comment: I can't think of a good example off the top of my head, but for all practical purposes you can really treat these two expressions the same way.